# Pcl Visualizer In Visual Studio 2010 Using Cmake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, point-cloud-library

I am using pcl-visualizer on visual studio 2010.I build the files using cmake but when it is running,it is displaying only some options (as in printusage func) in the command prompt, and not further displaying or manipulating the point cloud(it is making an exit from command prompt as any key is pressed).I used PCL 1.6.0 and cmake 3.9.0.
Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <pcl/common/common_headers.h>
#include <pcl/common/common_headers.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>

void printUsage (const char* progName)
{
std::cout << "\n\nUsage: "<<progName<<" [options]\n\n"
<< "Options:\n"
<< "-------------------------------------------\n"
<< "-h           this help\n"
<< "-s           Simple visualisation example\n"
 << "-r           RGB colour visualisation example\n"
            << "-c           Custom colour visualisation example\n"
            << "-n           Normals visualisation example\n"
            << "-a           Shapes visualisation example\n"
            << "-v           Viewports example\n"
            << "-i           Interaction Customization example\n"
            << "\n\n";
}


boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> simpleVis (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr cloud)
{
  // --------------------------------------------
  // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud-----
  // --------------------------------------------
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
  viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud, "sample cloud");
  viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "sample cloud");
  viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);
  viewer->initCameraParameters ();
  return (viewer);
}


boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> rgbVis (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr cloud)
{
  // --------------------------------------------
  // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud-----
  // --------------------------------------------
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(cloud);
  viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud, rgb, "sample cloud");
  viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 3, "sample cloud");
  viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);
  viewer->initCameraParameters ();
  return (viewer);
}


boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> customColourVis (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr cloud)
{
  // --------------------------------------------
  // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud-----
  // --------------------------------------------
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ> single_color(cloud, 0, 255, 0);
  viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud, single_color, "sample cloud");
  viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 3, "sample cloud");
  viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);
  viewer->initCameraParameters ();
  return (viewer);
}


boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> normalsVis (
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr cloud, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::ConstPtr normals)
{
  // --------------------------------------------------------
  // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud and normals-----
  // --------------------------------------------------------
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(cloud);
  viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud, rgb, "sample cloud");
  viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 3, "sample cloud");
  viewer->addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal> (cloud, normals, 10, 0.05, "normals");
  viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);
  viewer->initCameraParameters ();
  return (viewer);
}


boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> shapesVis (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr cloud)
{
  // --------------------------------------------
  // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud-----
  // --------------------------------------------
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(cloud);
  viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud, rgb, "sample cloud");
  viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 3, "sample cloud");
  viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);
  viewer->initCameraParameters ();

  //------------------------------------
  //-----Add shapes at cloud points-----
  //------------------------------------
  viewer->addLine<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud->points[0],
                                     cloud->points[cloud->size() - 1], "line");
  viewer->addSphere (cloud->points[0], 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, "sphere");

  //---------------------------------------
  //-----Add shapes at other locations-----
  //---------------------------------------
  pcl::ModelCoefficients coeffs;
  coeffs.values.push_back (0.0);
  coeffs.values.push_back (0.0);
  coeffs.values.push_back (1.0);
  coeffs.values.push_back (0.0);
  viewer->addPlane (coeffs, "plane");
  coeffs.values.clear ();
  coeffs.values.push_back (0.3);
  coeffs.values.push_back (0.3);
  coeffs.values.push_back (0.0);
  coeffs.values.push_back (0.0);
  coeffs.values.push_back (1.0);
  coeffs.values.push_back (0.0);
  coeffs.values.push_back (5.0);
  viewer->addCone (coeffs, "cone");

  return (viewer);
}


boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewportsVis (
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr cloud, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::ConstPtr normals1, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::ConstPtr normals2)
{
  // --------------------------------------------------------
  // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud and normals-----
  // --------------------------------------------------------
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
  viewer->initCameraParameters ();

  int v1(0);
  viewer->createViewPort(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, v1);
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0, v1);
  viewer->addText("Radius: 0.01", 10, 10, "v1 text", v1);
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(cloud);
  viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud, rgb, "sample cloud1", v1);

  int v2(0);
  viewer->createViewPort(0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, v2);
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, v2);
  viewer->addText("Radius: 0.1", 10, 10, "v2 text", v2);
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZRGB> single_color(cloud, 0, 255, 0);
  viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud, single_color, "sample cloud2", v2);

  viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 3, "sample cloud1");
  viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 3, "sample cloud2");
  viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);

  viewer->addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal> (cloud, normals1, 10, 0.05, "normals1", v1);
  viewer->addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal> (cloud, normals2, 10, 0.05, "normals2", v2);

  return (viewer);
}


unsigned int text_id = 0;
void keyboardEventOccurred (const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent &event,
                            void* viewer_void)
{
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer = *static_cast<boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> *> (viewer_void);
  if (event.getKeySym () == "r" && event.keyDown ())
  {
    std::cout << "r was pressed => removing all text" << std::endl;

    char str[512];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < text_id; ++i)
    {
      sprintf (str, "text#%03d", i);
      viewer->removeShape (str);
    }
    text_id = 0;
  }
}

void mouseEventOccurred (const pcl::visualization::MouseEvent &event,
                         void* viewer_void)
{
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer = *static_cast<boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> *> (viewer_void);
  if (event.getButton () == pcl::visualization::MouseEvent::LeftButton &&
      event.getType () == pcl::visualization::MouseEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
  {
    std::cout << "Left mouse button released at position (" << event.getX () << ", " << event.getY () << ")" << std::endl;

    char str[512];
    sprintf (str, "text#%03d", text_id ++);
    viewer->addText ("clicked here", event.getX (), event.getY (), str);
  }
}

boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> interactionCustomizationVis ()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
  viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);

  viewer->registerKeyboardCallback (keyboardEventOccurred, (void*)&viewer);
  viewer->registerMouseCallback (mouseEventOccurred, (void*)&viewer);

  return (viewer);
}


// --------------
// -----Main-----
// --------------
int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // --------------------------------------
  // -----Parse Command Line Arguments-----
  // --------------------------------------
  if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-h") >= 0)
  {
    printUsage (argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }
  bool simple(false), rgb(false), custom_c(false), normals(false),
    shapes(false), viewports(false), interaction_customization(false);
  if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-s") >= 0)
  {
    simple = true;
    std::cout << "Simple visualisation example\n";
  }
  else if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-c") >= 0)
  {
    custom_c = true;
    std::cout << "Custom colour visualisation example\n";
  }
  else if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-r") >= 0)
  {
    rgb = true;
    std::cout << "RGB colour visualisation example\n";
  }
  else if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-n") >= 0)
  {
    normals = true;
    std::cout << "Normals visualisation example\n";
  }
  else if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-a") >= 0)
  {
    shapes = true;
    std::cout << "Shapes visualisation example\n";
  }
  else if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-v") >= 0)
  {
    viewports = true;
    std::cout << "Viewports example\n";
  }
  else if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-i") >= 0)
  {
    interaction_customization = true;
    std::cout << "Interaction Customization example\n";
  }
  else
  {
    printUsage (argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  // ------------------------------------
  // -----Create example point cloud-----
  // ------------------------------------
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr basic_cloud_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  std::cout << "Genarating example point clouds.\n\n";
  // We're going to make an ellipse extruded along the z-axis. The colour for
  // the XYZRGB cloud will gradually go from red to green to blue.
  uint8_t r(255), g(15), b(15);
  for (float z(-1.0); z <= 1.0; z += 0.05)
  {
    for (float angle(0.0); angle <= 360.0; angle += 5.0)
    {
      pcl::PointXYZ basic_point;
      basic_point.x = 0.5 * cosf (pcl::deg2rad(angle));
      basic_point.y = sinf (pcl::deg2rad(angle));
      basic_point.z = z;
      basic_cloud_ptr->points.push_back(basic_point);

      pcl::PointXYZRGB point;
      point.x = basic_point.x;
      point.y = basic_point.y;
      point.z = basic_point.z;
      uint32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(r) << 16 |
              static_cast<uint32_t>(g) << 8 | static_cast<uint32_t>(b));
      point.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
      point_cloud_ptr->points.push_back (point);
    }
    if (z < 0.0)
    {
      r -= 12;
      g += 12;
    }
    else
    {
      g -= 12;
      b += 12;
    }
  }
  basic_cloud_ptr->width = (int) basic_cloud_ptr->points.size ();
  basic_cloud_ptr->height = 1;
  point_cloud_ptr->width = (int) point_cloud_ptr->points.size ();
  point_cloud_ptr->height = 1;

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----Calculate surface normals with a search radius of 0.05-----
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal> ne;
  ne.setInputCloud (point_cloud_ptr);
  pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ());
  ne.setSearchMethod (tree);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals1 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
  ne.setRadiusSearch (0.05);
  ne.compute (*cloud_normals1);

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----Calculate surface normals with a search radius of 0.1-----
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals2 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
  ne.setRadiusSearch (0.1);
  ne.compute (*cloud_normals2);

  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer;
  if (simple)
  {
    viewer = simpleVis(basic_cloud_ptr);
  }
  else if (rgb)
  {
    viewer = rgbVis(point_cloud_ptr);
  }
  else if (custom_c)
  {
    viewer = customColourVis(basic_cloud_ptr);
  }
  else if (normals)
  {
    viewer = normalsVis(point_cloud_ptr, cloud_normals2);
  }
  else if (shapes)
  {
    viewer = shapesVis(point_cloud_ptr);
  }
  else if (viewports)
  {
    viewer = viewportsVis(point_cloud_ptr, cloud_normals1, cloud_normals2);
  }
  else if (interaction_customization)
  {
    viewer = interactionCustomizationVis();
  }

  //--------------------
  // -----Main loop-----
  //--------------------
  while (!viewer->wasStopped ())
  {
    viewer->spinOnce (100);
    boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000));
  }
}
```

Comment: Which command line arguments do you handover?

Comment: I am using  windows10.

Comment: For options I used arguments mentioned like: -s,-r and others but it didn't work,The cmd window made an exit.